# Web filters not invoked for /q/health endpoints

Tags: quarkus, multi-tenant, requestfiltering

I'm working on a multi tenant application in Quarkus where I have a `ContainerRequestFilter` to resolve the tenant context of an incoming request. This works as it should for my application endpoints.

I would also like to implement tenant specific health checks. However, I've noticed that my tenant context filter is not being invoked for request to `/q/health` endpoints (probably generally for `/q`) I guess this is, as these are "special" endpoints which are more seperated from the application configuration.

Is there a way that I can register a web filter for these "system" endpoints, so I can have a tenant context when invoking a health check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Endpoints under `/q/` are not implemented in JAX-RS (Jakarta REST nowdays), but use Pure Vert.x instead.

Therefore their invocation cannot be "filtered" via JAX-RS `ContainerRequestFilter`.

You can instead try the Quarkus specific `@RouteFilter` as explained [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes#intercepting-http-requests).

It would look something like:

```
public class SomeFilter {

    @RouteFilter(1000) 
    void myFilter(RoutingContext rc) {
       // do something
       rc.next(); // continue the request chain 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it generally works. I use the filter to set a `@RequestScoped` value. The request scope data seems to be lost  when using it in my api controller. with a regular ContainerFilter, this works as expected, not so with the vertx filter. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I opened an issue for the folllow up: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34693